# Read and return data from json file in laravel 4

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, laravel-4

I have a file called data.txt in the public path , it has this

```
{"data":[{"name": "Jack", "age": 13},{"name": "Mary", "age": 15}]}
```

and I want to read these data and also return the age for both Jack and Mary,

I know that I can read the file using the decode_json(file_get_contents) but I have no clue how to fetch the data and return specific records from it.

Any help is much appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load the file and decode the content with:

```
$content = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true);
```

This will give you the associative array that contains your JSON content.

You can access data in user objects like that:

```
$userData = $content['data']; // content of "data" field
$jackData = $userData[0]; // first object in "data" array - Jack
$jackName = $jackData['name']; // Jack's name
```

Comment: I fixed one typo (missing $ - that's something your IDE should detect), apart from that the code works

Comment: yes i already know about the typo and fixed it, 
also the array inside json file was missing a '}' at the end of it